# Extension intl not loading when Xampp is ran as Windows service

Tags: php, apache, xampp, intl

I have a Xampp installation on Windows. When I run apache from the Xampp control panel the service `intl` is available when I use the `phpinfo()` function.

BUT. When I run the apache via the windows services screen (it's path: "C:\Xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice)
Then the `intl` extension is not loaded.

Please prevent me from losing even more hair and solve this issue with me.

Update:
Eror in error.log:
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: \\xampp\\php\\ext\\intl (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden), \\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_intl.dll (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden)) in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had to copy a bunch of dll's from the php8 folder into the apache/bin directory. The `ic*71.dll` files.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I ran `php -m` with `extension=intl` in php.ini. My PHP version is `8.3`. Finally, I found the solution.

1. From [this link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php) I know that intl is a wrapper of icu library.
2. Then I find icu [download page](https://icu.unicode.org/download/). The latest version is icu74.
3. Download icu74 release from https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-74-1.
4. Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2022 is a dependency of icu74 and you can download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).
5. Uncompress the icu zip package and add the unzipped bin64 directory (eg: `C:\icu4c-74_1-Win64-MSVC2022\bin64`) to the system variable `%PATH%`.
6. Now you can run `icuinfo` to verify that icu is installed normally.
7. Run `php -m`, then the error should be gone.